# How to secure multiple war files in tomcat 7

Tags: java, security, tomcat7

I need advice on how to get maximum security on my current Java website.

I've got both these application deployed under one instance of tomcat-7 on port 8080 on a Centos6 server.

**.war files**

- website.war (context name is ROOT)
- processor.war (context name is processor)

**batch jar**

- batch.jar

**security requirement**

- website.war is publicly accessible. No security needed
- processor.war gets HTTP requests from website.war and returns results for website to display to user.
- batch.jar run in the background on the server so I guess no security needed other than a secure server.

Currently I've added  to web.xml of processor.war to secure the following

- Only requests that have user and pass set with 'user' role in tomcat-users.xml file can access the /process url.
- Only requests that have user and pass set with 'admin' role in tomcat-users.xml file can access the /admin url.

Here is my configuration for processor.war's web.xml file.

```
  <security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection> 
        <web-resource-name>Admin</web-resource-name> 
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern> 
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint> 
        <role-name>admin</role-name> 
    </auth-constraint>
 </security-constraint> 
  <security-constraint> 
    <web-resource-collection> 
        <web-resource-name>Public</web-resource-name> 
        <url-pattern>/processor/process*</url-pattern> 
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>user</role-name>
        <role-name>admin</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
  </security-constraint>
```

Is this secure enough ? I've read that attackers can spoof the requests and read the passwords in HTTP requests. I would just like to really secure processor.war so that

- only website.war (localhost:8080) can post requests to processor.war localhost:8080/processor/process
- and only admin users can access localhost:8080/processor/admin page.

Can someone please tell me is more security is necessary, if yes, what can I do to secure it ?

Comment: This article might be of interest, if you're not already familiar with the subject: [Tomcat – Digest Authentication](http://techannotation.wordpress.com/2012/07/02/tomcat-digestauthentication/)

Comment: I didn't know about this. Thanks heaps Paul. I will implement DIGEST auth-method instead of BASIC. This should be it right ? Will I need any more security ?

Comment: This is more a sysadmin task: "front" tomcat with a reverse proxy (like Apache) which opens port 80 (or better 443) and proxies to your website war and, if needed, the admin page of your processor.war. Block port 8080 to all except to local calls. Once you have basic security in place, you cant tune authorizations

Answer (score 0):

How I have understood architecturally you have separated Front End from Back End. Front end without security vulnerabilities but you want to protect you back end Services (or Some html,css,js files if exist)

Please explain why do you need this approach if you can do this with understandable way?

Tomcat is a Servlet Container this means all things here is a Plain Java. That's why you can easily secure any URL do you like. Or you can construct self (Custom) Role or Permission Based Security System. Additionally with help of Filter Interface you can filter any url any requested file in you App Server particular App (WAR).

Here is a brief example:

```
@WebFilter("/secured/*")
public class LoginFilter implements Filter {

    /**
     * @see Filter#doFilter(ServletRequest, ServletResponse, FilterChain)
     */
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        System.out.println(" loginFilter servlet begin ");
          HttpServletResponse httpResponse = (HttpServletResponse) response;
          HttpServletRequest httpRequest = (HttpServletRequest) request;
          String URI = ((HttpServletRequest)request).getRequestURI();
          HttpSession session =httpRequest.getSession(false);
          String emailFromWeb = null;
          String loginURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/login.html";
          String rootURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/secured/root.html";
          String userURL = httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/secured/user.html";
          String logoutURL=httpRequest.getContextPath() + "/logout";

          if(session==null){
              System.out.println("false inquery session is null");
              httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
              return;

          }
          emailFromWeb  = session.getAttribute("email").toString();     

          System.out.println(" email from Session "+emailFromWeb);


              if  (httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(loginURL)){
                  System.out.println("login page inquery");
                  chain.doFilter(request, response);
                  return;
              } 
              if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().matches(".*(css|jpg|png|gif|js)")){
                    System.out.println(" inquery by "+httpRequest.getRequestURI());
                    chain.doFilter(request, response);
                    return;
                }

              if (httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(rootURL)&&Authentication.isPermitted(emailFromWeb, "RootPage")) {
                  System.out.println("root page inquery");
                  chain.doFilter(request, response);
                  return;
              } 

              else if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(userURL)&&Authentication.isPermitted(emailFromWeb, "UserPage")){
                  System.out.println("user page inquery");
                  chain.doFilter(request, response);
                  return;
              }
              else if(httpRequest.getRequestURI().equals(logoutURL)){
                  System.out.println("logout inquery");
                  httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
                  return;
              }
              else {
                  System.out.println("false inquery");
                  httpResponse.sendRedirect(loginURL);
                  return;
              }



    }
}
```